# How can i take a photo using canon camera lib and show the taken image photo in the pictureBox? Getting errors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a solution by someone here:

the easiest way to do this is to subscribe to an event when the image is downloaded.
To do this, go to the SDKHandler class, region Custom Events and this event:
Hide   Copy Code
public event ImageUpdate ImageReady;
Then in the region Eventhandling, method Camera_SDKObjectEvent at the case ObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransfer, replace this
Hide   Copy Code

```
DownloadImage(inRef, ImageSaveDirectory);
```

with this:
Hide   Copy Code

```
if (ImageReady != null) ImageReady(DownloadImage(inRef));
```

So instead of downloading the taken image to the hd, you download it into an Image and fire the ImageReady event.

Now all you have to do is subscribe to the event when the MainForm is initialized with this:
Hide   Copy Code

```
CameraHandler.ImageReady += new SDKHandler.ImageUpdate(SDK_ImageReady);
```

(just put it under the other event subscribing lines)
and now you have the event happening with this method:
Hide   Copy Code

```
private void SDK_ImageReady(Image img)
{
   LiveViewPicBox.Image = img;
   //you may want to save the image to the hd too. it would work like this:
   //img.Save(@"C:\Path\To\Save\image1.jpg");
}
```

But i can't pass the first steps i'm getting error.

This is what i did in the Custom Events region:

```
#region Custom Events

        public delegate void CameraAddedHandler();
        public delegate void ProgressHandler(int Progress);
        public delegate void StreamUpdate(Stream img);
        public delegate void BitmapUpdate(Bitmap bmp);
        public delegate void ImageUpdate(IntPtr objects);

        /// <summary>
        /// Fires if a camera is added
        /// </summary>
        public event CameraAddedHandler CameraAdded;
        /// <summary>
        /// Fires if any process reports progress
        /// </summary>
        public event ProgressHandler ProgressChanged;
        /// <summary>
        /// Fires if the live view image has been updated
        /// </summary>
        public event StreamUpdate LiveViewUpdated;
        /// <summary>
        /// If the camera is disconnected or shuts down, this event is fired
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler CameraHasShutdown;
        /// <summary>
        /// If an image is downloaded, this event fires with the downloaded image.
        /// </summary>
        public event BitmapUpdate ImageDownloaded;

        public event ImageUpdate ImageReady;

        #endregion
```

I added the lines:

```
public delegate void ImageUpdate(IntPtr objects);
public event ImageUpdate ImageReady;
```

Then i changed switched the lines like he said in the solution in the SDKObjectEvent:

```
private uint Camera_SDKObjectEvent(uint inEvent, IntPtr inRef, IntPtr inContext)
        {
            //handle object event here
            switch (inEvent)
            {
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_All:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemCancelTransferDT:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemContentChanged:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemCreated:
                    if (DownloadVideo) { DownloadImage(inRef, ImageSaveDirectory); DownloadVideo = false; }
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemInfoChanged:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemRemoved:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransfer:
                    if (ImageReady != null) ImageReady(DownloadImage(inRef));
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_DirItemRequestTransferDT:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_FolderUpdateItems:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_VolumeAdded:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_VolumeInfoChanged:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_VolumeRemoved:
                    break;
                case EDSDK.ObjectEvent_VolumeUpdateItems:
                    break;
            }

            return EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK;
        }
```

The line i switched to is:

```
if (ImageReady != null) ImageReady(DownloadImage(inRef));
```

On the line i'm getting error on the right side on:

```
ImageReady(DownloadImage(inRef));
```

The error is:

Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.IntPtr'

But if i will remove from the ImageUpdate the argument:

```
public delegate void ImageUpdate();
```

Now i'm getting error on the same line:

```
if (ImageReady != null) ImageReady(DownloadImage(inRef));
```

This time the error also on the right side say:

Error   2   Delegate 'ImageUpdate' does not take 1 arguments

So i'm stuck here.

This is the DownloadImage method:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Downloads a jpg image from the camera into a Bitmap. Fires the ImageDownloaded event when done.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ObjectPointer">Pointer to the object. Get it from the SDKObjectEvent.</param>
        public void DownloadImage(IntPtr ObjectPointer)
        {
            //get information about image
            EDSDK.EdsDirectoryItemInfo dirInfo = new EDSDK.EdsDirectoryItemInfo();
            Error = EDSDK.EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo(ObjectPointer, out dirInfo);

            //check the extension. Raw data cannot be read by the bitmap class
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(dirInfo.szFileName).ToLower();
            if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg")
            {
                SendSDKCommand(delegate
                {
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    IntPtr streamRef, jpgPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
                    uint length = 0;

                    //create memory stream
                    Error = EDSDK.EdsCreateMemoryStream(dirInfo.Size, out streamRef);

                     //download data to the stream
                     lock (STAThread.ExecLock) { DownloadData(ObjectPointer, streamRef); }
                     Error = EDSDK.EdsGetPointer(streamRef, out jpgPointer);
                     Error = EDSDK.EdsGetLength(streamRef, out length);

                     unsafe
                     {
                         //create a System.IO.Stream from the pointer
                         using (UnmanagedMemoryStream ums = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)jpgPointer.ToPointer(), length, length, FileAccess.Read))
                         {
                             //create bitmap from stream (it's a normal jpeg image)
                             bmp = new Bitmap(ums);
                         }
                     }

                     //release data
                     Error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(streamRef);

                    //Fire the event with the image
                     if (ImageDownloaded != null) ImageDownloaded(bmp);
                 }, true);
            }
            else
            {
                //if it's a RAW image, cancel the download and release the image
                SendSDKCommand(delegate { Error = EDSDK.EdsDownloadCancel(ObjectPointer); });
                Error = EDSDK.EdsRelease(ObjectPointer);
            }
        }
```

The owner of this project answered for this error the second one:

the DownloadImage(IntPtr) method does not return the image (it returns void).
But since the event expects to get an image it says it can't convert void to image.
You need to fire that event from within the DownloadImage method where you have the image object.

I didn't understand what to do.
I tried to cut and show only the code i have a problem with.

The whole project is here:

[Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp?fid=1848314&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx)

I know this question have some code but i couldn't cut it more to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a Browse button1 to browse and search for the image then display it on the picture box?

```
        private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(OFD.FileName);
            NewUserPictureBox.Image = Image;
            NewUserPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }
    }
```